# Applescript to Windows script (VB or java)

Tags: applescript, vbscript

I want to have a button in Powerpoint (2003) and have it open iTunes to a specific playlist and start playing using AppleScript

```
tell application "iTunes"  
    play playlist "iTunes DJ"  
end tell
```

How can I achieve the same in Windows, perhaps by using VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the iTunes Windows SDK API via VBA. Here is an article which gives you the foundations: [How to control iTunes from any Microsoft Office application](http://thousandrobots.com/blog/archives/2006/01/how-to-control-1/).